# How to migrate ngx-typesafe-forms to Angular 14+ typed forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Since version 14, Angular provides [Typed Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms) allowing to specify types for forms.

Before version 14 there was no such feature, and I've been using [ngx-typesafe-forms](https://github.com/dirkluijk/ngx-typesafe-forms) to have typed forms.

Now I need to migrate all my forms from this external library to the integrated Angular's typed forms, however, there is an issue.

Assuming that my type is for example:

```js
interface MyType {
    field1: string;
    field2: number;
}
```

With `ngx-typesafe-form` I could create a `FormGroup` like this:

```js
const form = new FormGroup<MyType>({
    field1: new FormControl(''),
    field2: new FormControl(0),
});
```

The above does not work with Angular's typed forms, because they actually want the type to be specified with the `FormControl` instead:

```js
interface MyType {
    field1: FormControl<string>;
    field2: FormControl<number>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a new `FormGroup` class that I can use to facilitate this migration, which rely's on Angular's native typed forms and is supposed to replace directly the one from `ngx-typesafe-forms`.

The migration is easy if you have simple forms:

```js
export type ModelForm<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>;
};

export class TypedFormGroup<T> extends FormGroup<ModelForm<T>> {}
```

then `TypedFormGroup` can be exported as `FormGroup` from an `index.ts` file and then it's just about replacing the `ngx-typesafe-forms` FormGroup's `import` with this new one.

However things get more complex if you have nested form groups and form arrays.

With nested form groups it is still quite easy, I all had to do is to further edit my `ModelForm` type using recursion:

```
export type ModelForm<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]> | FormGroup<ModelForm<T[K]>>;
};
```

But things got more tricky when I had to support form arrays as well, resulting in the following final code:

```js
type Flatten<Type> = Type extends Array<infer Item> ? Item : Type;

export class TypedFormArray<T> extends FormArray<FormControl<T> | TypedFormGroup<T>> {}

export type ModelForm<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any>
    ? TypedFormArray<Flatten<T[K]>> | FormControl<T[K]>
    : FormControl<T[K]> | FormGroup<ModelForm<T[K]>>;
};

export class TypedFormGroup<T> extends FormGroup<ModelForm<T>> {}
```

and in my `index.ts` I had to export both the new `FormGroup` and the new `FormArray` to be used instead of ngx-typesafe-form's:

```
export { TypedFormGroup as FormGroup, TypedFormArray as FormArray } from './migration-forms';
```